# MongoDB storing random data

Tags: java, database, spring, mongodb, dataset

I'm stuck as to how to approach this problem.

I have a very large dataset with ~million records. Each line contains a person, his/her ID, and his/her address. But a person may have multiple addresses, and the data isn't organized at all.

Reading from the .csv file, I am forced to chunk the data when creating instances of the Person object because the dataset is so large. At the same time, I want to create a schema such that one person record contains the ID, and a list of addresses (I want to aggregate the addresses corresponding to one person and create a single Person object out of it). What would be the easiest way to approach this? Should I create some sort of intermediate schemas and try to combine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be the following :

- import all your csv chunks in a collection, let's say 'temp' (yes, it will be temporary)

After that, your shema should look like this (depending of your csv) :

```
{_id : ObjectId(abcd11241545),   
id : 001                                     <======== your id
address : {
    street : "56 avenue des Champs Elysee",
    street2 :"",
    zip : "75000",
    city:"Paris",
    country:"France"    
    }
}
{_id : ObjectId(abcd11241545),   
id : 001    
    address : {
        street : "23 rue de la plage",
        street2 :"Residence du soleil",
        zip : "06000",
        city:"Nice",
        country:"France"    
    }
}
```

- perform an [aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) on that collection to group by ID, add unique adress(es) in an array, and create a new collection "persons" with [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage :

  ```
   db["temp"].aggregate([
   {$group:{
      _id:"$id",
      addresses : {$addToSet : "$address"}
      }
   },
   {$out : "persons"}
   ])
  ```

This will produce the collection (persons) (or override it, beware if it already exists), with the following document structure :

```
{_id : 001,   
addresses : [
    {street : "56 avenue des Champs Elysee",
    street2 :"",
    zip : "75000",
    city:"Paris",
    country:"France"},

    {street : "23 rue de la plage",
    street2 :"Residence du soleil",
    zip : "06000",
    city:"Nice",
    country:"France"}
    ]
    }
}
```

If your collection is very large, create an index on your id field in temporary collection, this will improve performances of your aggregation.